# How to transfer money from my razorpay account balance to user UPI ID or bank account

Tags: razorpay

Is there any other way to transfer money from our Razorpay balance to a user-defined UPI id or bank account instead of a refund. Because refund my take 4-5days it may affect our business that to refund can be done to a particular payment ID. Let me explain with a scenario:: There are 3 users A, B, C ... user A transfer 200 to our Razorpay account similarly B = 300, C = 500. So my total Razorpay balance is 1000. Now, user B sent a withdrawal request of 200rs via his balance of 300. By this 200rs should be debit from our account and credited to user B UPI id or bank account. Debit from by Razorpay balance and credit to the Users bank account.

Answer (score 0):

By Using Direct transfers you can send any amount to users bank account.
for more details Kindly check this link [#RazorPay Direct transfer Doc.](https://razorpay.com/docs/route/api/transfers/#direct-transfers)